Why is ASP.NET razor page blinking black on reload
I Faced strange behaviour from framework in my project - on every page load almost every page item blinks black for like fraction of second.
After some time i finally checked if clean default mvc project template behaves the same, and yes, it does.
It behaves like this only on Google Chrome (browser i am mostly using)
What can cause this issue?
Blinks I am talking about
I tried to delete everything except single  tag that navigates to exact same page but it still blinks black.
tried also to reseting browver apearance settings but it doesnt make any difference.
also rebooted pc and also without any improvements

almost looks like a video card problem.  (bad driver?)  Or possibly an issue in your version of Chrome.  (Go to Help>About and include version of Chrome you are using)

According to me, since the page seems simple (you have not yet created a large application), there is almost no chance of the error being within the CSS/JS.
You can try doing these steps to fix the project:

Forcefully refresh the browser with Ctrl+F5.

Try to clear history of your browser and re-run the project (or you can try to run the project in an incognito window).

Check if there is problem in a NuGet package you have installed (unlikely).

It could be due to a bug in a driver on your device (maybe from an update).



Tried to open page in incognito mode and it worked just fine, messed around and when I finally removed all chrome extensions issue went away. dont know which one was the one who caused issue but it worked.
Thanks for help <3

FYI: after checking. I found out that the Dark Reader Extension is the cause
